# Is the JSON CSRF/Theft attack still possible?

Tags: javascript, security, json

I read this article: http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/2007/01/gmail-xsrf-json-call-back-hackery.html

And I tried to use the technique, but it seems to fail on (at least) most browsers I tried. Basically you return JSON on your site and someone else does a `<script src="domain.com/response.php?json"></script>` and then you setup your own object/array constructors to steal the data.

Is this still viable with modern browsers? Should I use tokens to prevent this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

> Is this still viable with modern browsers?

Yes.  And browsers are not the issue.

Non-browser applications can make HTTP requests, also.  Applications like `curl` can probably be used for this kind of thing.  Or you can write something in Python using `urllib2` to do CSRF's.  You can easily fake out responses of all kinds if the framework doesn't properly include CSRF tokens.

> Should I use tokens to prevent this?

No.

You should find a framework that provides you the support for handling this.

Comment: How exactly are you going to use `curl` or a Python program to do a CSRF attack?  Where would you get the session cookie?

Comment: @Pointy: http://www.cgisecurity.com/csrf-faq.html.  "An attacker could embed scripting into a word document, Flash File, Movie, RSS or Atom web feed, or other document format allowing scripting"

Comment: Well my understanding of CSRF is that it really relies on an attacker leveraging an active session cookie in the browser. The attacking site uses the fact that HTTP requests from *any* window to some secured site will be made *with* the active session cookie if there's a logged-in window open. Otherwise, it's just a plain attack on an open URL.  In other words, URLs that work without an active session cookie just need to be protected plain and simple, and there's no "cross-site" aspect to the issue.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a **browser** that maintains the active session cookie; anything that does so *like* a browser would be similarly vulnerable. However, you can't just walk up to a command line and use `curl` to launch a CSRF attack against a victim without that victim's active session cookie.

Comment: I have been unable to make any of the CSRF <script> JSON exploits work in IE, Chrome 23, or even FireFox 3 today (December 2012), even with third-party cookies disabled. I can trick the browser into downloading data protected by a session cookie, but I can't trick the browser into actually *accessing* the data with the various Array and Object prototype tricks.

Comment: @djsmith It doesn't matter if you can't read the response. The server received what it believed was an authentic request. Just because you can't see "Roger, all things deleted" doesn't mean the server didn't do it. Also, up until fairly recently there was a way to read json array responses by hacking the array constructor before sending the request. You couldn't read the data directly but the array constructor was modified to post the data to an evil server.

Comment: Samuel: Of course the server got the request. There is a danger in that by itself (if the API uses GET requests to mutate server state). I was talking specifically about the ability for malicious pages to *read* cross-site JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

No, the [] constructor is no longer overrideable, and setters are no longer called for object initializers. See http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2011/05/30/json-hijacking/ and [Is JSON Hijacking still an issue in modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers/16880162#16880162) .