# $.getJSON always returns null

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to make this work but I don't understand why this always returns "Request Failed"?
The json seems to be valid (I know jQuery is strict about this), maybe it's because of the httpS?

```
var geo_url = "https://spapi.cdnspstr.com/api/get_geo_ip";

var jqxhr = $.getJSON(geo_url, {
    format: "json"
})
.done(function (json_data) {
    alert("currency: " + json_data.data.currency);
})
.fail(function () {
    alert("Request Failed");
});
```

Comment: If you are trying to access a file from a different domain, then your subject to the [*same-origin policy*](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy). If the server does not enable CORS you cannot load the file via Ajax.

Comment: I am able to make the request using jsonp, which allows cross domain JSON requests. http://jsfiddle.net/p2bra/

Answer (score 1):

```
var geo_url = "https://spapi.cdnspstr.com/api/get_geo_ip";

$.ajax({
    url: geo_url,
    data: {
        format: "json"
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json_data) {
        alert("currency: " + json_data.data.currency);
        alert("city: " + json_data.data.city);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Request Failed");
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/pEZSU/)

Comment: Can you explain what you changed? Why does this work? Code without an explanation is usually not that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The request should be done using jsonp as cross-domain json-ajax requests are not allowed

```
$.ajax("https://spapi.cdnspstr.com/api/get_geo_ip",{
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json_data) {
        alert("currency: " + json_data.data.currency);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("Request Failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: *"cross-domain json-ajax request are not allowed"*: Cross-domain Ajax requests (no matter whether JSON or not) are not allowed by *default* but they can be if the server enables CORS.

Comment: I tested this code & it works...I guess the ajax call with 'jsonp' does the trick here

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe due to [JSON hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers). If that is the case, you have to explicitly allow get JSON on server side.

I don't know which technology you use on server side. If you're using ASP.NET MVC, you have to allow get JSON using `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Comment: Uh? Why does this have anything to do with JSON hijacking?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I'm working with ASP.NET MVC and I have to use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`, otherwise javascript cannot load the JSON even on the same domain. The reason for this is JSON hijacking.

Comment: Ok, but what if the service uses PHP on the backend? The statement *"Due to JSON hijacking, you have to explicitly allow get JSON on server side."* is simply wrong because it is generalizing. The actual problem is probably the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, debug:

```
var geo_url = "https://spapi.cdnspstr.com/api/get_geo_ip";

var jqxhr = $.getJSON(geo_url, {
    format: "json"
})
.done(function (json_data) {
    alert("currency: " + json_data.data.currency);
})
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
    alert("Request Failed");
});
```

If there is any error in the backend (500, 403, ...), you will get `Request Failed` anyway.