# How is hijack prevented by prefixing the string like this?

Tags: java, json, spring, security, web

I saw the following comment in Spring JSON `messageConverter`:

```
/**
 * Indicate whether the JSON output by this view should be prefixed with "{} &&". Default is false.
 * <p>Prefixing the JSON string in this manner is used to help prevent JSON Hijacking.
 * The prefix renders the string syntactically invalid as a script so that it cannot be hijacked.
 * This prefix does not affect the evaluation of JSON, but if JSON validation is performed on the
 * string, the prefix would need to be ignored.
 */
```

How does string prefixing work to prevent JSON hijacks?

Comment: Great, I didn't know that Spring supports this. Could you please share which class and package this comment is in?

Comment: @Sanjay it is `org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` - see `setPrefixJson()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrived example: say Google has a URL like mail.google.com/json?action=inbox which returns the first 50 messages of your inbox in JSON format. Evil websites on other domains can't make AJAX requests to get this data due to the same-origin policy, but they can include the URL via a  tag. The URL is visited with your cookies, and by [overriding the global array constructor or accessor methods](http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/) they can have a method called whenever an object (array or hash) attribute is set, allowing them to read the JSON content.

The `{} &&` prevents this: an AJAX request at mail.google.com will have full access to the text content, and can strip it away. But a  tag insertion blindly executes the JavaScript without any processing. Since `{}` is a falsey value the actual response would never be parsed

Other frameworks add different content to the response, like `while(1);` (example from Google) which causes an infinite loop for a hacker, but we can strip it out on our own site

Answer (score 0):

The addition of the prefix will invalidate the string.

I think you may want to check this Stackoverflow question and comments to it:
[Difference between ")]}',\n" and "{} &&" in avoiding json hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999572/difference-between-n-and-in-avoiding-json-hijacking)