# CSRF prevention for GET requests

Tags: javascript, web, csrf

From what I've read, CSRF prevention seems to focus on (1) making GET requests side-effect-free and (2) using only POST requests with CSRF tokens to alter state.  It seems to me, though, that this assumes that the only objective an attacker might have would be to maliciously update the victim website.  What if the attacker just wants information which can be retrieved via a GET request?  Couldn't someone embed a sensitive resource from the victim site into the attacking site and interact with it via Javascript?

So my questions are (1) is that possible, and (2) how do you prevent it?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/

Comment: I'm a little confused about why the trickery is necessary there.  Couldn't the attacker just run `$.get('http://vulnerable.example.com/json')`?

Comment: @Kiwi — No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attacker *could* include the following script on their page:

```
$.get('http://vulnerable.example.com/json')
```

However, due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), the JavaScript on the attacker's domain couldn't read the response. The same origin policy checks whether the domain, protocol and port match - if they don't the JavaScript will encounter a security error when trying to read the response. For example, this is the warning Chrome gives when trying to access an IFrame from another domain - this is exactly the same mechanism that will protect the JavaScript response.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': blocked a frame with origin "http://evil.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://vulnerable.example.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

So in summary, POST requests must use a CSRF token as the POST request will still be made even though the response cannot be read and GET requests are not  normally a cause for concern as the response cannot be read and they are non destructive. There was the issue with JSON Hijacking, but you have to go back as far as Firefox 3 to find a browser vulnerable to this. See [Is JSON Hijacking still an issue in modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16289894/413180)

Answer (score 2):

If an attacker had a way to receive the server's response to the victim's request (the response would be transmitted to the victim's browser, but not transmitted to the attacker), then the attacker could potentially benefit from a CSRF GET request.

However, in a typical CSRF scenario, the attacker does not have access to the response, because it is transmitted from the server to the victim's web browser (and not transmitted to the attacker). Usually the intent is to cause some state change, such as initiating a payment, sending an email, etc, which is usually initiated by a client making an HTTP request with a method like PUT, POST, PATCH or DELETE.

Comment: "the attacker does not have access to the response, because it is transmitted from the server to the victim's web browser" - the attacker can include malicious javascript on the page to transmit the information back to the attacker, though, couldn't they?

Comment: In a pure CSRF vulnerability, an attacker can't include javascript on the page. If the attacker can exploit a cross-site scripting vulnerability (distinct from CSRF), however, then he can just initiate synchronous XHRs to perform whatever GETs he'd want anyway, so CSRF vulnerability wouldn't matter at that point.