# Tornado - JSON Output sent as Response to be wrapped in dictionary

Tags: python, json, http, tornado, httpresponse

I came across this section in the docs :

> `RequestHandler.write(chunk)`
>
> Writes the given chunk to the output buffer.
>
> To write the output to the network, use the flush() method below.
>
> If the given chunk is a dictionary, we write it as JSON and set the
>   Content-Type of the response to be application/json. (if you want to
>   send JSON as a different Content-Type, call set_header after calling
>   write()).
>
> Note that lists are not converted to JSON because of a potential
>   cross-site security vulnerability. All JSON output should be wrapped
>   in a dictionary. More details at
>   http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/ and
>   https://github.com/facebook/tornado/issues/1009

So I have a few questions related to this:

1. What does it mean by this?

> If the given chunk is a dictionary, we write it as JSON.

2. What does it mean by this?

> Note that lists are not converted to JSON because of a potential
>   cross-site security vulnerability.

3. What does it mean by this? And here, what does it mean by **JSON** output? And why to wrap it in a dictionary?

> All JSON output should be wrapped in a dictionary.

4. This has two subparts :

   a. What is the best way to send **JSON responses** from **Tornado** to **client**?

   b. What is a better way to send responses? If not JSON, then what is? And if it JSON, then just mention the answer to subpart (a).

***Please try to answer all the parts and their subparts in numbered  manner so that I can understand them properly.***

Comment: Do you have any background about *JSON* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > What does it mean by this?
   >
   > > If the given chunk is a dictionary, we write it as JSON.

It means, that if you pass dict to `write` it will we be [automatically](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L692) json encoded. Method `write` can handle `dict`, `byte`, `unicode_type` (simplifying it is str).

2. > What does it mean by this?
   >
   > > Note that lists are not converted to JSON because of a potential  cross-site security vulnerability.

Assume that you provide some service and with request `/example/my_service/user_data.json` and JSON response.

If top level object would be an array like:

```
["John Smith", "email@mail"]
```

Then attacker could redefine Array's constructor and then add script tag with `/example/my_service/user_data.json`, that gets evaluated immediately  - array is created with attacker's constructor. This is because **standalone array is valid javascript** code.

Since standalone objects, except empty one, are not valid JS, so if you return

```
{"name": "John Smith", "email":"email@mail"}
```

Attacker end up with `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` or something similar.

More info http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/

3. > What does it mean by this? And here, what does it mean by JSON output? And why to wrap it in a dictionary?
   >
   > > All JSON output should be wrapped in a dictionary.

As you read above, it becomes pretty clear, top-level element in JSON should not be an `array`. Moreover Tornado will raise error if you pass `list`.Of course you can bypass this safety, simply passing string (json dumps before wirte), but it is not wise:

```
self.write('["this", "is", "wrong"]')
```

4. > a. What is the best way to send JSON responses from Tornado to client?
   >
   > b. What is a better way to send responses? If not JSON, then what is? And if it JSON, then just mention the answer to subpart (a).

I use, if possible, json or xml as a response. But I am not using Tornado's mechanism for that, I pass already encoded object -  string to `write`. The reason is, that it's the cleanest way to override Tornado's encoders and use e.g. [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson/1.34).

**edit**

Worth noting that [modern browsers should not vulnerable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880162/681044).

Comment: Thanks man. So what happens when I use the escape.json_encode(response) and then do self.write(response), given the fact my response is itself a dictionary. So it is json encoded now, so what will happen now? Which if statements in https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/web.py#L692 does it satisfy?

Comment: Also why is it a benefit to use ujson (or any other 3rd party json library) when tornado provides its in-house json module? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: `json_encode` serialize objcet to json, it returns string with encoded object, so write will treat that like string.

Comment: And what is the benefit of using the 3rd party json module?

Comment: why `ujson`? I use it with high-load json-rpc apps with large objects, it is only matter of performance http://blog.dataweave.in/post/87589606893/json-vs-simplejson-vs-ultrajson. But as usual it is not for free http://mod16.org/hurfdurf/?p=266,  https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/issues/134