# ASP.NET Web API Return JSON as an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Currently the Web API which queries the Oracle DB is returning the result in the JSON in the below format.

```
[{"CATEGORY":"Internal Study","SESSION_NUMBER":7,"SESSION_START_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00","SESSION_START_TIME":"2015-02-13T10:33:59.288394"}]
```

Below is the code we are using

```
public class SampleController : ApiController
{
  public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
   {
     using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=J;PASSWORD=C;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=T"))
      {
     var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
    var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
    DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
    var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY where STPR_STUDY.STD_REF IN(" + srtcon + ")";
    OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn);
    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand);
    DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(selectResults);
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, selectResults,MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
    if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
    {
       response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }
    return response;
 }
}
```

But the Client which has the Script which consumes the file says that JSON structure being an array instead of an object is a security hole.

```
  {"data":[{"CATEGORY":"Internal Study","SESSION_NUMBER":7,"SESSION_START_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00","SESSION_START_TIME":"2015-02-13T10:33:59.288394"}]}
```

I am new to this JSON structure and not sure how we will be manipulate the returned data as an object in JSON File

Comment: What do you mean by "client" here? Who says this is a security hole?

Comment: I see that the top one is the returned one now, the bottom one is what you want :P The security hole is that a top level JSON array can be hijacked as it is a valid JavaScript script, where as a JSON object is not.

Comment: @starlight54 Are you sure? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289894/is-json-hijacking-still-an-issue-in-modern-browsers

Comment: @starlight54 Exactly. The top one is currently being returned as an array but the data will be executed in the browser as part of a script. They want now as an object

Comment: @DavidG There'll be a douche somewhere who's still running an ancient browser on Windows ME, of course it's their fault then, but it's a minor inconvenience to avoid the use of top level JSON arrays, and because they're valid JS, other vulnerabilities could be found or introduced later.

Comment: @starlight54 Maybe, but why should anyone support browsers that are a decade old? Let them worry about their own security risks. They've got bigger problems than worrying about JSON hacking.

Comment: @starlight54 how will be converting the JSON array in to the Object. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking to convert json array to C# objects ?

Comment: See this to deseralize ur json http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard of any security issue around an array within the JSON, however if you need to convert it to a JSON object you could use a generic object that you define:

```
var returnObject = new
{
    selectResults = selectResults
};
```

This will add the JSON object wrapping you want onto the response, which you can then use this code to build your response:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject,MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
```

Sorry if I have misunderstood what you are asking for - hope this helps/works.

Comment: Thank you. But do we assign selectResults to itself? Also it says type expected in the new()

Comment: Sorry, the code I provided had an extra '()' in it after the 'new' - this isn't needed; I have amended my solution to fix this and it should work now, I tested it out myself. Also - the 'selectResults' that is being assigned to in the new object will be the name of the JSON property; in " {"data":[{"CATEGORY":"Internal Study","SESSION_NUMBER":7,"SESSION_START_DATE":"2015-02-13T00:00:00","SESSION_START_TIME":"2015-02-13T10:33:59.288394"}]} " it would be in the position the 'data' tag is.

Comment: Almost there, to change the name to data change your code to the following: var returnObject = new { data = selectResults }; this will change the name of the JSON object to 'data'