# How can I modify the Object constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

When I run the following code

```
var ExtendedObject = function() {
  this.standard = 5;
};

Object = ExtendedObject.bind(Object);
var p = new Object();
console.dir(p.standard);
```

, the output is

> 5

as expected.

If I instead instantiate the variable p as an object literal like this:

```
var ExtendedObject = function() {
  this.standard = 5;
};

Object = ExtendedObject.bind(Object);
var p = {};
console.dir(p.standard);
```

The result is

> undefined

I am trying to find a way to modify the constructor of Object such that I can add some standard content to all new objects being created.

Comment: when `var p = {};` is empty then result would be undefined Obviously, yes try `var p = Object` it would work

Comment: What is `.bind(Object)` supposed to do?

Comment: The `this` in a constructor function is different from to the `this` in object methods by "definition". The `this` in the constructor always refers to  the new object to be instantiated. Accordingly you can not `bind` it to any ambigious context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the property on the prototype of Object like this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'standard', {
  value: 5,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
var p = {};

console.dir(p.standard);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, it is absolutely impossible to redefine how an object literal evaluates; it will always become a native object with the builtin `Object.prototype`, not a subclass or anything and it will also not invoke a custom constructor.

This is in fact a security feature, as it prevents [JSON hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16289894/1048572).

> … such that I can add some standard content to all new objects being created

That's a horrible idea and will break *every* library you'd ever use in this environment (including all functions you'd write yourself). However, if you insist on having a common (not individual!) property on all objects, you might consider [defining it on `Object.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13296897/1048572). Not that I would recommend it, but at least do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class and extend it from `Object`.

```js
class MyObject extends Object {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.standard = 5;
  }
}

const obj = new MyObject();
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is ES6 implementation and is supported by most of the modern browsers. Feel free to use it,
For more Info refer  http://es6-features.org/#ClassInheritance

Comment: I think OP's goal is to have all objects inheriting from Object have its set properties. i.e even object literals would have the `standard` property.

Comment: I did not want that. I basically want to add functionality to an application without modifying what is already written. This is a principle of BDD - Behavior Driven Design.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a helpful link that discuss about JavaScript objects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Please point out which part of that article that answers my question. I fail to see it.