# defineproperty on object.prototype does not fire when creating nested objects

Tags: javascript, object, defineproperty

I'm just fiddling around trying to understand how his is supposed to work, but this scenario has me confused.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'a', {set: function() {console.log("Set!");} });
```

With that method, I assume any time I create an object called a, that function should fire. It works here:

```
a = {};
Set!
```

But not when nested like this:

```
test = {a:{}};
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

The object literal `{a: …}` is creating a new object with an own property. It does not call any inherited setters for the property creation, in part to [prevent JSON hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16289894/1048572).

However, the following code will have the desired behaviour:

```
test = {};
test.a = {};
```